# function attribute referring to an id in quotes

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

```
this.createEmptyMovieClip("noise1",getNextHighestDepth());
noise1 = new Sound(noise1);
noise1.attachSound("noise1");
noise1.start(0,99999);
noise1.setVolume(0);

this.createEmptyMovieClip("noise2",getNextHighestDepth());
noise2 = new Sound(noise2);
noise2.attachSound("noise2");
noise2.start(0,99999);
noise2.setVolume(0);

this.createEmptyMovieClip("noise3",getNextHighestDepth());
noise3 = new Sound(noise3);
noise3.attachSound("noise3");
noise3.start(0,99999);
noise3.setVolume(0);
```

how do i condense these into a function. a function that looked something like this:

```
function soundclip(soundname){
    this.createEmptyMovieClip("soundname",getNextHighestDepth());
    soundname = new Sound(soundname);
    soundname.attachSound("soundname");
    soundname.start(0,99999);
    soundname.setVolume(0);

}
```

i want soundname to replace all of the soundname in the function, including those in quotes. they must have the same name. i would call the functions like this:

```
soundclip(noise1);
soundclip(noise2);
soundclip(noise3);
```

that would generate what's above. i'm bad with syntax. i've tried everything involving using quotes in the function, or nowhere at all and i tried using toString() with no success.
thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the sound object and assign it to the named variables:

```
function soundclip(soundname){
    var mc = this.createEmptyMovieClip(soundname + "_mc",getNextHighestDepth());
    var sound = new Sound(mc);
    sound.attachSound(soundname);
    sound.start(0,99999);
    sound.setVolume(0);
    return sound;
}



noise1 = soundclip("noise1");
noise2 = soundclip("noise2");
noise3 = soundclip("noise3");
```

Comment: according to the debug screen, this.createEmptyMovieClip(soundname,getNextHighestDepth());
doesn't work. it doesn't create an mc with the name specified.

the sound loads but is not controllable with my existing method.

Comment: My bad, I didn't pay enough attention to the names.  I changed my answer accordingly. You can access the MovieClips as "noise1_mc", etc.